# Tracking Followers Over Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

I want to build functionality in my Rails application that shows follower trends over time.

Currently, my following methodology involves creating and destroying relationship objects - following creates an object with the IDs of the follower and followed and unfollowing deletes that relationship object.

Since the relationship object is deleted upon an unfollow, it's impossible to go back and look at how many followers existed for a followed at any given time.

To solve this, the best solution I can think of is this:

Instead of deleting a relationship object upon unfollowing, create a new object with a negative value of, say, -1. Following would create an object with a positive value of +1. Therefore, adding up the total values for a given pair would yield whether or not they were currently following (1 or 0), while historical trends could also be calculated by adding up the total following values for a given followed.

My question is: Is this the most elegant solution this problem? Is there an easier way to do it? I realize that it's possible to use cron jobs to output a daily number, but that seems like it would duplicate data. Any other suggestions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add an active field then instead of deleting the relationship record I would set the record to inactive. Then you'll have to update all of your user facing queries to reflect active = 1. Then you can use the records with active = 0 for reporting purposes. You can also add a deactivated_at field that stores the date that the record was deactivated.

An example scenario would be user 1 follows user 2, follows user 3, follows user 4, un-follows user 2, re-follows user 2, un-follows user 4.

```
follower_id followed_id active created_at deactivated_at
1           2           0      9/10/2012  9/13/2012
1           3           1      9/10/2012  NULL
1           4           0      9/10/2012  9/17/2012
1           2           1      9/16/2012  NULL
```

Comment: I think this is the best idea for my purposes to limit the database entries and still have the functionality. Thanks!

Comment: why do you need active and deactivated_at?

Answer (score 1):

just use `paranoia`

https://github.com/radar/paranoia

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_paranoid

  ...
end
```

(if you have a **unique** index over the two numeric ID columns, remove it, use a plain index)

Then you can have

```
def currently_following_count(uid)
  Relationship.where(:followed_id => uid).count
end

def historical_following_count(uid)
  Relationship.unscoped.where(:followed_id => uid).count
end
```

Comment: I like this idea (it's probably the best solution for most people), but I'm trying to stay away from using third-party gems as much as possible... I've had some plugins that I've used fall behind and then break my apps after the fact and they were too poorly documented for me to take on.

Comment: well, you have to choose carefully what you use of course, but don't reinvent the wheel. `paranoia` is 48 lines of code, so you'll be able to hack it in case of need.

Comment: That's true, I'll take a look at it and see if I can use some parts of it for my needs, too. I'm upvoting your answer as well!